# How to avoid `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` for some component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

When the Box  with `fillMaxSize` modifier applied then inside this Box a Button which is aligned to Bottom get top of the keyboard. I want to go top for TextInputField but not the bottom Button. can we remove android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" only for the button?